# Various input for one function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

I know that I can have various input number by using `varargin`.

However, if you type `sparse(` in MATLAB, you can see that the input argument names are different for the number of input arguments.

[image: various input arguments]

I want to make such input style.

Is it possible to make such function? or is it only limitted to built-in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `inputParser` class and the `addOptional` method. Basically, MATLAB checks for the argument and if it does not exist in the function call, assigns a default value to it.

From [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html):

> addOptional(p,argName,default) adds optional input, argName, to the
>   input parser scheme of inputParser object, p. When the inputs that you
>   are checking do not include a value for this optional input, the input
>   parser assigns the default value to the input.
>
> addOptional(p,argName,default,validationFcn) specifies a validation
>   function for the input argument.

See docs for [inputParser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) and [addOptional](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html) for examples.